# Can I open a new xterm using tcl and send commands on that xterm

Tags: tcl, expect, xterm

I am having a strange requirement. I want to open new xterm using tcl and send commands on that xterm. I googled it but could not get anything

Example : I am having a GUI with 4 buttons. When I click on button1 then it will open new xterm and send commands related to button1 on that xterm.

Similarly when i click on button2 it will open another xterm window and it will send commends related to button2 on new xterm

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Expect doesn't automate GUI applications, not even one as “simple” as xterm.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do this using the `-S` option of xterm.  Don Libes has an example called `multixterm` which uses this feature.  That sends characters to/from the xterm(s).

For the side comment about buttons — that would have to be done using buttons in the tcl/tk interface (getting X events *from* xterm would be more difficult).

Further reading:

- [multixterm - drive multiple xterms separately or together](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/multixterm.man.html)
- [Execute commands on multiple hosts using expect tool](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/execute-commands-on-multiple-hosts-using-expect-tool-part-iii.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write a temporary Expect script to a file from the main one and run that temporary script in your xterm. E.g.,

```
#! /usr/bin/env expect
package require Tk 8.5
package require fileutil ;# You need to have Tcllib installed for this.

proc action1 {} {
    set temp [::fileutil::tempfile]
    ::fileutil::writeFile $temp {
        # Delete the temporary file as soon as it has been read.
        file delete $argv0

        # Your Expect script for Action 1 follows here.
        puts {Hello from a new Expect process!}
        sleep 3
    }
    exec xterm -e expect -f $temp &
}

# Display the GUI.
grid \
    [::ttk::button .action1 -text {Action 1} -command action1] \
    [::ttk::button .quit -text Quit -command {exit 0}]

vwait forever
```

Alternatively, you could have a predefined, non-temporary Expect script file for each command. You can run it similarly with

```
exec xterm -e expect -f action1.exp &
```

from Expect or `tclsh`.